# How to find a particular running cron jobs with github.com/robfig/cron?

Tags: go, cron

How do we look for particular running cron jobs within [github.com/robfig/cron](https://github.com/robfig/cron)?

In a notification service, where we store notifications in database, each notification either is to send (to user) immediately or scheduled.

The scheduled ones are sent using cron jobs. If a scheduled notification was deleted before it sent, how do we look for the cron job to be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

With [`github.com/robfig/cron/v3`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/robfig/cron/v3) You can use [`Cron.Entry`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/robfig/cron/v3#Cron.Entry).

This is a basic usage example:

```
job := cron.FuncJob(func() {
    fmt.Println("Hello Cron")
})

c := cron.New(/* options */) 
entryId := c.Schedule(cron.Every(time.Second*5), job)

// Find the job entry
entry := c.Entry(entryId)
// ... here you can inspect the job `entry`

// Removes the entry, it won't run again
c.Remove(entryId)
```

[`cron.FuncJob`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/robfig/cron/v3#FuncJob) is actually just a wrapper around `func()`. In case you need more complex behavior, or state, you can implement the [`Job`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/robfig/cron/v3#Job) interface yourself:

```
type myJob struct{}

func (j *myJob) Run() {
    fmt.Println("foo")
}
```

Then you can fetch the specific instance of your job by type-asserting:

```
j := c.Entry(id).Job.(*myJob)
// ... do something with the *myJob instance
```

You can also customize the schedule, by implementing [`Schedule`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/robfig/cron/v3#Schedule) interface:

```
type mySchedule struct{}

// Next returns the next activation time, later than the given time.
// Next is invoked initially, and then each time the job is run.
func (s *mySchedule) Next(time.Time) time.Time {
    return time.Now().Add(time.Second*5)
}
```

And then use it all like:

```
c := cron.New(/* options */) 
entryId := c.Schedule(&mySchedule{}, &myJob{})
```

---

If you use an earlier version of the package, unfortunately you can't get a single entry by id and `Cron.Schedule` doesn't assign ids either. You must manage a lookup table yourself. If possible, I recommend upgrading to `v3`.